# custom NSTableCellView in NSTableView, sometimes cell blank, maybe related with scroll and resize

Tags: resize, scroll, nstableview

I have a `NSTableView` which is a list of a custom `NSTableCellView` (only one column). The problem is, after resize and/or scroll and/or some `NSPredicate` filtering, some rows are not shown, only a blank cell in the row, but there is a `NSImage` picture is shown correctly, ALWAYS, wonder if this has something related with `NSTableCellView.imageView`.

I think this has something with the scroll/cache settings inside `NSTableView`, but I just don't have experience on Cocoa guessing where to begin. The table view is cocoa bound with `NSArrayController`, which uses core data for storage. Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: this problem is gone, become invalid as my project goes on/survives til today :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange behaviour, but something that I have observed.

I was using hi-res artwork (`300x300px` images) and allowing the `NSTableCellView` to scale the image down. When I supplied the table cell view with `20x20px` images the text was never missing.